# How to plot multiple histograms without overlapping in R

Tags: r, plot

Can you tell me without installing additional libraries is there a way to plot  dynamically multiple histograms in R without over laping. Dynamically in the sense plotting histograms with change in number of columns. Below code only have 4 columns but can change between 2 and 20 columns.

example plot

[image]

My code

```
set.seed(3)
Ex <- xts(1:100, Sys.Date()+1:100)
df = data.frame(Ex,matrix(rnorm(100*4,mean=123,sd=3), nrow=100))
df<-df[,-1]

for(i in names(df)){
dfh<-hist(df[[i]], plot=FALSE)
}
plot(dfh,main="Histogram",xlab="x",col="green",label=TRUE)
```

This only plots the last histogram

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to have multiple plots in the same screen you can use the command

```
par(mfrow = c(2,1))
```

Where c(2,1) means you would like to have 2 rows and 1 column of charts, putting your charts side by side. If you put c(1,3) you would be telling R to put your charts in 1 row and 3 columns, and so on and so forth.

Then just plot your charts one after the other and they will fill the correspondent space.

EDIT: if you want to calculate automatically the row and columns for the par function you can create a function like this (or something more refined and pass it to par)

```
dimension = function(df){
kk = dim(df)[2];

x = round(sqrt(kk),0);
y = ceiling(kk/x);

return(c(x,y))
}
```

Being your code

```
set.seed(3)
Ex <- xts(1:100, Sys.Date()+1:100)
df = data.frame(Ex,matrix(rnorm(100*4,mean=123,sd=3), nrow=100))
df<-df[,-1]

par(mfrow = dimension(df))

for(i in names(df)){
    hist(df[[i]] ,main="Histogram",xlab="x",col="green",label=TRUE,plot = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but how should i used it for variable number of columns. As I mentioned before some times my data frame contains variable number of columns between 2 and 20 (didnt included code for those). Do I need to manually change col and row in `par(mfrow = c(2,2))` or is there a better way to fully automate this eg: consider `rnorm(100*n,mean=123,sd=3` where `n<-sample(2:20,1)` for random number of columns

Comment: You can always define a function to calculate for you the rows and columns based on your data frame, I've edited the code

Answer (score 3):

Or if you are interested in making use of **`dplyr`** / **`tidyr`** and `ggplot2` you can use the code below. The idea is to *gather* the variables you want to visualise and then pass the generated categories to *facets* in `ggplot2`. This will give you a lot of flexibility in terms of arranging your charts by making use of [**`facet_grid`**](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/facet_grid.html) / [**`facet_wrap`**](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/facet_wrap.html) and basic `data.frame` transformations. Personally, I find `dplyr` / `ggplot2` combination very powerful and pleasant to read when working with a longer workflow.

## Code

```
# Libs and data
Vectorize(require)(package = c("ggplot2", "ggthemes", "tidyr", "dplyr",
                               "xts"),
                                     character.only = TRUE)
set.seed(3)
Ex <- xts(1:100, Sys.Date()+1:100)
df = data.frame(Ex,matrix(rnorm(100*4,mean=123,sd=3), nrow=100))
df<-df[,-1]

# Chart and data transformations
df %>%
    # Reshape
    gather(key = indicator, value = val) %>%
    # Basic chart
    ggplot(aes(x = val)) +
    geom_histogram(colour = "darkgreen", fill = "gray") +
    facet_wrap(~indicator, nrow = 2) +
    ## Theme and looks 
    theme_economist() +
    ggtitle("Histograms") +
    theme(strip.background = element_rect(fill = "gray80", colour = "black",
                                          size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"),
          strip.text = element_text(face = "bold"))
```

## Preview

[image: Facets: Histogram]